# Playing melodies in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, piano

Is there any way to play sequence of notes in javascript piano sound. I've found a lot of libraries that can play a specific note but I assume that playing notes and making delays between would not be so good for performance. Is there any way to do it?

I'm willing to write it on my own, but I need a place to start.

EDIT: I decided to do it in java applet since it's easyer.

Comment: Well, there is no other way of delay being notes without actually delaying...

Comment: Why do you assume it would be bad for performance? anyway, until the Web MIDI API gets decent implementations, you're stuck with Web Audio which is fairly low level and you'll have to provide it with your own piano sounds. You *can* use Web Audio to shift the sound's pitch to produce a range of notes from a single original sample (which is how cheap synths do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at [Blob](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) for a start. MS has a small [demo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Demos/tree/master/blobbuilder) at Github (License: Apache 2.0) that even works with Firefox (vers. 41.0.1). The simple monophonic version works well but I haven't tried to build a more complex or even polyphonic version and hence cannot say much about the scalability of this approach.